# Similar `for` loop output in R like Python

Tags: python, r

How to i get exact output in R like python

In python:

```
for i in range(1,6):
    print(i ,"",end = "")

1 2 3 4 5
```

In R:

```
for(i in seq(5)){
    print(i)
}

[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
```

I need to print everything  in one line like `python` output

Comment: You can try with `cat` i.e. `cat(seq(5), '\n')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the @akrun comment

```
for( i in seq(5)){
     cat(i,"")
         }

 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Do note @akrun is not using `for` loop at all.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for can be done in 1 line in R-

```
arr<-seq(1, 5, 1)
arr
```